# jqGrid DatePicker filtering without hitting Enter key

Tags: jqgrid

I'm building my first ASP.NET MVC 3 app and using jqGrid.  One of my columns, "Flavor Created", is a date column and I'd like to filter the grid on that column using the DatePicker.  Here's what currently happens:  The user clicks on the column header filter box, the date picker is displayed and then the user chooses the year, month and clicks a day.  The picker goes away and leaves the date, say, 03/28/2009, in the text box.  To actually get the filter to work, I have to click into that box and hit the Enter key, which is a bit annoying for the user.

Is there a way to have the filter automatically fire when the user clicks that day?

*(As an aside, I am not sure what the use of the 'Done' button is for since the picker goes away whenever I click a day.  Perhaps that is a setting I'm missing.)*

Anyone else needed this functionality and solved it?

I tried to do something like this:

```
dataInit: function (elem) {
  $(elem).datepicker({ changeYear: true, changeMonth: true, showButtonPanel: true,
    onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
       $("#icecreamgrid")[0].trigger("reloadGrid");
    }
  })
}
```

as I saw someone on some website suggest, but that didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can try with

```js
dataInit: function (elem) {
    $(elem).datepicker({
        changeYear: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        onSelect: function() {
            if (this.id.substr(0, 3) === "gs_") {
                // in case of searching toolbar
                setTimeout(function(){
                    myGrid[0].triggerToolbar();
                }, 50);
            } else {
                // refresh the filter in case of
                // searching dialog
                $(this).trigger("change");
            }
        }    
    });
}
```

**UPDATED**: Starting with the version 4.3.3 jqGrid initialize the DOM of grid as `this` of `dataInit`. Thus one don't need to use `myGrid` variable in the above code. Instead of that one can use:

```js
dataInit: function (elem) {
    var self = this; // save the reference to the grid
    $(elem).datepicker({
        changeYear: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        onSelect: function() {
            if (this.id.substr(0, 3) === "gs_") {
                // in case of searching toolbar
                setTimeout(function () {
                    self.triggerToolbar();
                }, 50);
            } else {
                // refresh the filter in case of
                // searching dialog
                $(this).trigger("change");
            }
        }    
    });
}
```

Free jqGrid calls with the second `options` parameter of `dataInit`, which contains additional information, like the `mode` property. The value of `mode` property is `"filter"` in case of calling inside of the filter toolbar (and `"search"` in case of searching dialog). Thus one can use the following code

```js
dataInit: function (elem, options) {
    var self = this; // save the reference to the grid
    $(elem).datepicker({
        changeYear: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        onSelect: function() {
            if (options.mode === "filter") {
                // in case of searching toolbar
                setTimeout(function () {
                    self.triggerToolbar();
                }, 0);
            } else {
                // refresh the filter in case of
                // searching dialog
                $(this).trigger("change");
            }
        }    
    });
}
```

Comment: That's works pretty well Oleg.  Thanks. Hitting Esc causes the GET to happen but I can live with that - I'm not pulling back that much data.  I might be able to call a func that checks before calling triggerToolbar().

Comment: Probably you should better call `triggerToolbar` inside of `onSelect` and not inside of `onClose`? You can describe exactly in which situation you want to force toolbar searching and in which not. In general the `onSelect` is the event which are called if the user choose new date.

Comment: @itsmatt: You are welcome! I changed the code from my answer follow other directly to the better way.

Comment: @itsmatt: I thought a little about the problem and tried to made a demo. Now I think that the usage of `onSelect` like I described here is not the best in case of the usage both Advanced Searching and the Filter Toolbar. I will examine the problem more exactly at the weekend and will post more information later.

Comment: @itsmatt: I modified the answer one more time. Now it works in case both kind of searching.

Comment: I had also same issue while hitting enterkey when select date, now resolved. Thankx for valuable solution.

Comment: @Farhan Siddiqui: You are welcome! By the way if you would more vote the answers which was *helpful* for you other people would better find it. The searching engine use voting counter as the main criteria for the order of the searching results.